# Using PowerShell to connect to Project Online with CSOM under MFA

Tags: powershell, csom, authentication, office-dev-pnp, project-online

I am trying to interact with a PWA on a tenant for which I have no choice but to use MFA. I'm trying to use the OfficeDev-PnP library which supports MFA, but can't get it to work with Project Online.

This **works, but doesn't support MFA**

```
$siteURL = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa"
$username = "my.name@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)
# Create & configure a client context connection
$pctx.Credentials = $credentials
# ...load stuff
$pctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

This uses Office Dev PnP to obtain a MFA-friendly auth context, but **doesn't work** (I get a 403 on the `$pctx.ExecuteQuery()`)

```
$authmgr = new-object OfficeDevPnp.Core.AuthenticationManager
$pctx = New-Object Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.ProjectContext($siteUrl)
$pctx.Credentials = $authmgr.GetWebLoginClientContext($siteURL).Credentials
# ...load stuff
$pctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

This latter method works fine for a plain vanilla SharePoint Online ClientContext. Maybe the problem is that `$authmgr.GetWebLoginClientContext($siteURL)` returns a ClientContext, not a ProjectContext.

#### Edits:

- Per Gautam's suggestion, try to do `$pctx = $authmgr.GetWebLoginClientContext($siteURL)`: this fails when executing a query to load projects, with the *Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1"* message. Here, I believe $pctx doesn't know it's supposed to be a ProjectContext and is still a ClientContext (thus nothing has exercised the ProjectServer CSOM).

For completeness, here's the full code I've tried here:

```
# Load libraries
$PNPPath = "C:\Path\To\PnP"
Add-Type –Path "$PNPPath\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type –Path "$PNPPath\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PNPPath\Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PNPPath\OfficeDevPnP.Core.dll"

# do stuff
$siteURL = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa"
$authmgr = New-Object OfficeDevPnp.Core.AuthenticationManager
$pctx = $authmgr.GetWebLoginClientContext($siteURL)    
$projects = $pctx.Projects
$pctx.Load($projects)
$pctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

- I also tried directly casting the ClientContext to a ProjectContext `$pctx = [Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.ProjectContext]$authmgr.GetWebLoginClientContext($siteURL)` but this also fails, with a *Cannot convert...* error.

Comment: ProjectContext inherits ClientContext, so you should be able to use it as:

`$pctx = $authmgr.GetWebLoginClientContext($siteURL)` . Can you try that and check

Comment: @GautamSheth I think I tried that but let me do so and confirm for sure

Comment: Ok cool, any luck here ?

Comment: @GautamSheth Just tried that - see edits in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's another way to do this, but to get unstuck and do what I needed to do, I did the following:

- Forked the https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core repo
- Created a new method in /Core/OfficeDevPnP/AuthenticationManager.cs based on `GetWebLoginClientContext()` that instead returns a ProjectContext instead of a ClientContext (obviously involved a couple of tweaks to the solution)
- Built the solution and referenced the newly built `OfficeDevPnP.Core.dll` in my PowerShell code

`$pctx = $authmgr.GetWebLoginProjectContext($siteURL)`

Works like a charm.

Comment: Could you please able to share your work on this. I'm stuck at connecting to SharePoint using CSOM.